# What makes the posterior intractable?

Tags: bayesian, vae

In the setting of Variational AutoEncoders, i.e. when we want to find the posterior distribution

[image]

over the data generating, latent variable `z`, given some observations `x`, what exactly (which part of the equation) makes this posterior distribution intractable and why?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually the denominator $p(x)$ (the "evidence") which is intractable. You could attempt to compute it by marginalizing over the latent variable $p(x) = \int p(x|z)p(z)dz$. However, you would need to evaluate all possible values of $z$ which would require exponential time. (That's why in maximium-likelihood estimation you have no intractability problem because you can treat the evidence as a constant.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Might sharing some more insights on the "exponential time" part?

Comment: $z$ will usually be high-dimensional and to accurately sample from the large" volume of the space" you need exponentially many more samples for each additional dimension. ("curse of dimensionality"). even if there is a closed-form solution to the integral the computation can still be exponential see e.g. the example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00670.pdf)