# Why posterior in EM algorithm tractable but in VAE not?

Tags: bayesian, vae, expectation-maximization, gmm

So I've read through [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80272/what-makes-the-posterior-intractable/80675#80675?newreg=66a0c28abaf14ca78774f2be36751120), including the Bayesian Mixture of Gaussians supplied in the link in the last comment by oW_ there, to really see why the posterior is intractable.

I just don't see yet why in the EM algorithm when we need to compute the posterior, there it *is* tractable, but in VAE and Bayesian Mixture of Gaussians it isn't. What's the main difference?